# Involutory matrix under prime modulo

Tags: matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> A matrix $A \neq I $is called involutory modulo $m$ if $A^2≡I (\mod m).$
> Prove or disprove that if $A$ is a $2 × 2 $ involutory matrix modulo $m$, then $ \det(A) ≡
> ±1 (\mod m)$.

I already disprove this statement but I have doubt about what happens if $m=p$ be a prime.

I assume a matrix $A$ is involutory modulo $p$. Therefore it is the self-inverse matrix now,

$\det(A)^2=\Delta ^2=1(\mod p)$ from that I got
$\Delta =\pm1 (\mod p)$

Is this corect?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $\Delta^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ is equivalent to $p \mid (\Delta - 1)(\Delta + 1)$. It is well known that if a prime number divides the product of two numbers, then it divides one of the factors. So you are right.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p$, the ring of integers taken modulo a prime $p$ is a field. Working in this field, i.e. with $\Delta$ considered as an element in this field:$$0=\Delta^2-1=(\Delta+1)(\Delta-1)\ ,$$ and the vanishing of the product implies that one of the factors vanishes, a field property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is a multiplicative homomorphism, $\det:GL_n(R)\to R^{\times}$.  In your case, $R=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and you are looking at elements of order less or equal two in $GL_2(R)$, i.e. $A^2=1$.  If $A^2=1$, then $a^2=1$ in $R^{\times}$ where $a=\det(A)$.  So $a$ must be a square root of $1$.

In general, we have $R^{\times}=\prod_iR_i^{\times}$ if $R=\prod_iR_i$, so in your case we take a factorization $m=\prod_ip_i^{e_i}$ and have only to consider the stucture of $(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{e_i}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

These groups are cyclic for odd prime powers, so there are two square roots of unity in this case.

For powers of 2, we have

- $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=1$,
- $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ cyclic of order 2 (both elements are square roots of 1),
- $(\mathbb{Z}/2^e\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for $e>2$ is a product of two cyclic groups of order $2$ and $2^{e-2}$.

In any case, you can write down the determinant conditions (i.e. if $A$ has order less or equal two then $a\in S$ where $S$ is the set of square roots of 1).

Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n